# out of the scene elements overlap the previous scene during transitions

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a cocos2d based IPhone game where a scene replace another with a Left to Right Transition. The new scene has a background a bit bigger than the scene. That is just because I move it according to the device tilt to create a sort of 3D effect.

Unfortunately during the transition of the scene I can see the background outside the scene overlapping the previous one :(

I have then tried to use the z-order in such a way the previous scene should go on top of the new one bug it does not work the way it should.

do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need do crop your scenes layer by overriding it's -(void)visit method.
That's how I did it:

```
- (void) visit {
glPushMatrix();
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

glScissor(cropRect.origin.x, 
          cropRect.origin.y, 
          cropRect.size.width,
          cropRect.size.height);

[super visit];

glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glPopMatrix();
```

}

May be you'll need to play a bit with cropRect origin and size values.
Also you may need to add some device orientation changing support

Comment: hi GLvRzZZ and thank you for your answer. I have just finished to try the code. Unfortunately it seems the crop works after the transition is finished. It seems the visit method is called after the transition. My problem is that i'd like to crop the scene size during the transition as well otherwise, although for a second, the elements over the scene are visible.